VBA method FolderExists type mismatch error
The problem: VBA method FolderExists returns type mismatch error
Running simple VBA code expecting no error:
Sub testdir2()
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set smth = fs.FolderExists("c:\new\test")
End Sub


You need an object and a variable:
Sub testdir2() 

    Dim fs   As Object
    Dim smth As Boolean

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    smth = fs.FolderExists("c:\new\test") 

End Sub

